# How to do a change of variable here

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How to do a change of variable here $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}2\left|\sin\frac{(\theta-\theta')}{2}\right|\ d\theta\ d\theta'$

If I replace $\theta-\theta'$ by $u$, double integral will be reduced to a single integral, but what happens to the limits?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mvw can you elaborate please ?

Comment: This should decouple the interated integration tinto single integrations: $\sin(x-y) = \cos(y) \sin(x) - \cos(x) \sin(y)$

Comment: @SamuelLijin, yes that is the usual change of coordinates, where the determinant of the functional matrix accounts for the change in volume elements. I just don't see how to go from $d\theta\,d\theta'$ to just $du$, isn't there a second variable necessary?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the problem properly. If you are proposing a change of variables where $u\in\mathbb{R}:u=\theta-\theta'$, then this is not possible, as that would require capturing the behavior of your function over $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$ using some $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not possible.

Comment: @SamuelLijin In this book, the author did it, http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~jflegall/IPPA2.pdf#page=97

Comment: Why didn't you separate the integral into two terms, the first for $0<\theta<\pi$ and the second one is for $\pi<\theta<2\pi$. After that, you can evaluate the integral using $u=\dfrac{\theta-\theta'}{2}$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey you mean because of the absolute value, but then don't I have to do the same with $\theta'$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jacobian is the usual way to change the variables. In order to give an intuitive understanding of what happens, the figure below shows that the scales in the $(x,y)$ system and in the $(u,v)$ system are not equal : length ratio $=\sqrt(2)$. This explain why the ratio between $(dx dy)$ and $(du dv)$ is $=(\sqrt(2) )^2 = 2$

One understand that if only one integral (variable $v$) is taken into account, the length of a segment is obtained. In order to scan the whole square, another variable $u$ is necessary. This explaines why the change of the two initial variables requires not only one, but two new variables.

Finally, the result of the double integral is $16\pi$

Of course, in more complicated cases of change of variables, a graphical explanation and the related calculus would become too ardous. Then, thanks to the Jacobian.

[image]

Comment: My calculation is also get $16\pi$ but no need to change the variables. +1 for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: Of course, there is no need to change the variables : $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}2\left|\sin\frac{(\theta-\theta')}{2}\right|\ d\theta\ d\theta'$ = $2\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\theta'}2\sin\frac{(\theta-\theta')}{2}\ d\theta\ d\theta'$ = $2\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}4 \ d\theta'$ = $16\pi$

Answer (score 2):

You can reinterpret the integral as follows:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} 2 \left|\sin\frac{(\theta-\theta')}{2}\right| \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\theta' = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-y}^{-y+2\pi} 2 \left| \sin\frac{x}{2} \right | \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$$
which sort of corresponds to the change of variables you wish to perform. I'd think of this as a change of variables
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &-1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \theta \\ \theta' \end{pmatrix},$$
where the determinant of the Jacobian is just unity.

Here you can of course abuse the symmetry to actually evaluate the integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-y}^{-y+2\pi} 2 \left| \sin\frac{x}{2} \right | \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = 2\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{-y+2\pi} 2 \sin\frac{x}{2} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y.$$

Comment: this looks really strange, last integral gives $4\pi$ right ? thanks for your effort.

Comment: It will give the same answer as the original problem: $16\pi$. Nevertheless, as JJacquelin mentioned, the Jacobian is a neccessary concept to learn here. If you want to check the values of these sort of integrals in the future, I'd suggest using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) and writing the commands `Integrate[2*Abs[Sin[(x - y)/2]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}]` and `2*Integrate[2*Sin[x/2], {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {x, 0, -y + 2*Pi}]`.

Comment: yes I had already checked it before accepting the answer. your method is awesome, the problem was that I didn't understand it at first looking (now it's OK). Thanks a lot.